# How to work-around the restriction of primitive objects - like Integer, String - not being allowed to derive from?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, criteria-api

I realize that it is not possible to derive from primitive objects as they are declared final. How do I work around this restriction? I am programming with the JPA Criteria API. Almost everywhere I handle with my own methods having Integer/String parameters to compare against entity fields representing database table row values. On any of these parameters  I would like to accept `QueryParameter<Integer>` or `QueryParameter<String>`. Doing so I would have to create the method a second time accepting query parameters instead of the literals. However, thinking about value lists (as in the QueryBuilder's in(...) method) with permutating literals and query parameters, makes it hard or even impossible to implement.

Let us assume I had an entity `Car` with a method `withFeatures(StringRepresentation ... features)` and there would be literals and query parameters had derived from the same super-class `StringRepresentation` which itself would have be derived from the primitive type String. I would like to do so:

```
myCar.withFeatures("Seat Heating", "Metallic Color", "Trailer Hitch");
myCar.withFeatures(new QueryParam<String>("MyFavourit"));
myCar.withFeatures("Seat Heating", new QueryParam<String>("LoveThatColor"), "Trailer Hitch");
```

Has anyone an approach or even kind of a solution for this?

Comment: FWIW, neither Integer nor String is a 'primitive type' in Java.  The primitive types are the non-class types: int, float, etc.

Comment: You are right. Nevertheless, you cannot derive from because they are final.

Comment: It's because things like Integer and Double are just wrappers around the corresponding primitive types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time to solve that problem taking in the hints from the Java Community so far.
Of course I am a follower of Java's concept of type safety (thanks to plalx). Hence, my solution will probably has to do with parameterized types.
And also I do admiring the concept of design patterns like many others (thanks to tgdavies). Hence, I use the builder pattern with one method for each type of criterion. I will accept to implement car feature methods for

1. using plain old literals of String
2. as well as specifying parameters of String

That is:

```
myCar.withFeatures("Seat Heating", "Metallic Color", "Trailer Hitch");
```

as well as specifying (let's say) query parameters or String parameters of some kind with a slightly more complex way by using a static method sp(...)

```
myCar.withFeatures(sp("MyFavourit"));
```

and of course a mixture of both, introducing another static method sr(...) for string representation:

```
myCar.withFeatures(sr("Seat Heating"), sp("LoveThatColor"), sr("Trailer Hitch"));
```

The mixture of both is important in cases where we want to use variable arguments in method signatures to specify those representations, in this case car features.
As one can see, it is almost the usage I stated above when posting this question.
How can I achieve this?

At first I designed an interface to implement my different String representations against:

```
public interface ValueTypeRepresentation<T> {
    public Class<T> getClazz();
    public QueryParameter<T> getQueryParameter();
    public RepresentationType getRepresentationType();
    public T getValue();
}
```

The methods are to determine whether the representation is a literal or a parameter, and to get the literal's value resp. the parameter itself to later on use its name.
The clazz member is to ease the Java Generic Type Inference purposes because I will be using parameterized types to implement different type representations. As I said, String ist just the starter of the show.

Then I designed an abstract class to derive the concrete classes of representations of different primitive objects from:

```
abstract class AbstractValueTypeRepresentation<T> implements ValueTypeRepresentation<T>  {
    private Class<T> clazz;
    private RepresentationType representationType = RepresentationType.VALUE;
    private QueryParameter<T> queryParameter;
    private T value;

    public AbstractValueTypeRepresentation(Class<T> clazz, T value) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.representationType = RepresentationType.VALUE;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public AbstractValueTypeRepresentation(QueryParameter<T> qp) {
        this.clazz = qp.getClazz();
        this.representationType = RepresentationType.PARAM;
        this.queryParameter = qp;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public QueryParameter<T> getQueryParameter() {
        return queryParameter;
    }

    @Override
    public RepresentationType getRepresentationType() {
        return representationType;
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

To distinguish a literal of that type from the query parameter of that type, I introduced this enumeration:

```
public enum RepresentationType {
    PARAM, VALUE;
}
```

Then I designed the first concrete representation, here for my StringRepresentation (derived from the abstract class above):

```
public class StringRepresentation extends AbstractValueTypeRepresentation<String>  {
    public static StringRepresentation sr(String s) {
        return new StringRepresentation(s);
    }

    public static StringRepresentation sp(String name) {
        return new StringRepresentation(new QueryParameter<String>(String.class, name));
    }

    public StringRepresentation(String value) {
        super(String.class, value);
    }

    public StringRepresentation(QueryParameter<String> queryParameter) {
        super(queryParameter);
    }
}
```

Obviously this is easy to extend to representations of Integer, Float, LocalDate, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a builder pattern with one method for each type of criterion.

```
class Car {
  private Set<String> features = new HashSet();

  public Car withFeature(String f) {
    features.add(f);
    return this;
  }

  public Car withFeature(QueryParameter<String> q) {
    features.add(q.getStringRepresentation()); // or whatever
    return this;
  }
  ...
}
```

So you can say:

```
myCar.withFeature("Seat Heating")
   .withFeature(new QueryParam<String>("MyFavourit");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But this approach does not save me from muliplying methods if it comes to varargs methods as with withFeatures(String ... features).

Answer (score 0):

> with permutating literals and query parameters, makes it hard or even impossible to implement

You could leverage `CharSequence` for strings, but I'm not sure that's a god idea...

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        withFeatures("test", new StringQueryParam("test2"));
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public final static <T extends CharSequence> void withFeatures(T ...params) {
        // Wrap in StringQueryParam if not an instance of QueryParam<String>
    }

    interface QueryParam<T> {
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    static class StringQueryParam implements QueryParam<String>, CharSequence {
        private final CharSequence value;

        @Override
        public int length() {
            return value.length();
        }

        @Override
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return value.charAt(index);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return value.subSequence(start, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Having less verbose static factory methods (e.g. `QueryParam.of`, `QueryParam.all`, etc. for query params) mixed with builders or ways to combine them effectively could help.

e.g.

```java
// Assuming Lists.union util method
withFeatures(Lists.union(
    QueryParam.all("a", "b"),
    QueryParam.of("c")
));

// With static imports
withFeatures(union(params("a", "b"), param("c"));

// With ParamsBuilder
withFeatures(ParamsBuilder.of("a", "b").add(QueryParam.of("c").build())));
```

Hopefully that gives you some ideas on how to design the API! You may as well use a more complicated, but flexible route where the entire criteria is just an AST so that `QueryParam` really just is a type of `Expression` in the AST allowing to create composites, etc. If you look at QueryDSL everything is a `DslExpression` and you have visitors to execute operations against the tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It inspired me much. I would say "that is it" if I could limit myself to String. But String is just the opening of the show. My database fields also have Integer, Float, LocalDate and other types.

Comment: You will have to make concessions between ease of use and type safety. I prefer type safety here.